# Prove inequality $|a-b+c-d| \leqslant \frac{1}{16}$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers that fulfill two conditions:
$$a+b+c+d \leqslant 2$$$$ab+bc+cd+ad \geqslant 1$$
Prove that $|a-b+c-d|\leqslant \frac{1}{16}$

Let:
$a+c=x$ and $b+d=y$

Both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

$$x+y \leqslant 2$$$$xy \geqslant 1$$
$$-4xy \leqslant -4$$
$$(x+y)^2 \leqslant 4$$
$$(x-y)^2 \leqslant 0 \Rightarrow |a-b+c-d|=|x-y|=0\leqslant \frac{1}{16}$$

I do not really think that this is valid solution, but I can not find any mistakes.

Comment: @macavity Their sum wont be negative since $a,b,c,d$ are positive.

Comment: @Macavity When both sides of inequality are positive then squaring is equivelent operation.

Comment: Didn't notice they're positive.  In that case $x=y$ is the only possibility, your workings are correct.

Comment: Proof looks good to me.

Comment: I do not know why $\leq \frac{1}{16}$. To me, the two given inequalities do not seem possible unless $a+c = b+d$ for positive real numbers.

Comment: That's what I concluded, but I do not believe that this is that easy. It just seems weird

Comment: https://omj.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/om2017-tresci.pdf  eighth task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. One can shorten the argument as follows:

$$
  (a-b+c-d)^2 = (a+b+c+d)^2 - 4(a+c)(b+d) \\
= (a+b+c+d)^2 - 4(ab+bc+cd+da)\le 4 - 4 = 0
$$
which implies $a-b+c-d = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $$1\leq ab+bc+cd+da=(a+c)(b+d)\leq\left(\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\right)^2\leq1,$$
which gives $$a+c=b+d$$ and $$a+b+c+d=2$$ or
$$a+c=b+d=1,$$ which gives $$|a-b+c-d|=0<\frac{1}{16}.$$